# How to disable location listener when app goes background in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location, android-4.4-kitkat

Here's the case: `my app calls onPause: theLocationManager.removeListener(..)`.

In **android 4.4.2** the gps icon at top bar disappears and after some minutes it appears again (app still in background).
Icon will disappears if I remove the app from the recent list.

**Android 4.1.2** does not has this problem.

Any ideas of how to `disable gps` when app goes background? Is there a workaround for 4.4.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is may be to do with the way the destroying of activities has changed (not entirely sure though). I believe you want to do this in the onStop() method, so that when this activity is no longer visible, updates stop being requested.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   locationManager.removeUpdates(this); // Assuming the calling class implements a location listener
}
```

This should help, worth a try anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried to implement it in onStop method also, it still happens.
We're testing in a Nexus 4 device. Don't think is a device specific issue. I'll keep some investigation!

Comment: Is the class you are using for "this" definitely implementing a location listener? Also make sure you are not setting update listeners for the location manager anywhere else in the application. Good luck!

Comment: And you're definitely using removeUpdates(this) as opposed to removeListener()

Comment: Turns out that the app was adding the location listener on the onResume method of a custom base activity AND not using a singletlon location manager... so when it stops one, already starts another. I've fixed that and it's working fine! Thank you all!!!